# How about runtime environment needed for compiled IronPython script?

Tags: ironpython

I would like to make my compiled IronPython script run on other machine. So, I made a zip file for the following list of DLLs. (My script also compiled with pyc.py for making exe type.)

IronPython.dll
IronPython.Modules.dll
Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
Microsoft.Scripting.dll
MyScript.dll
MyScript.exe

Then, I moved it to other machine where .net framework from 2.0 to 4.0 were installed only.
When I ran the MyScript.exe, I could encounter a unhandled Exception on runtime. FYI, IronPython is not installed on the machine. However, the program is run well once I install the IronPython on the machine.

Should I install IronPython on the machine for successful execution?

Answer (score 0):

If you use any standard Python modules, you have to either include them when compiling MyScript.dll with pyc.py or put them onto target machine somewhere your script can find them - the easiest to the same folder as MyScript.dll.

Comment: All files was placed in same folder. What I really wonder is whether the IronPython interpreter should be installed on target machine or not.

Comment: If you have an .exe, you don't need interpreter. But I would try to copy the interpreter (ironpython.exe), script source and try to run the script on target machine with `-X:Debug -X:ExceptionDetail` parameters to see detailed Exception info.